How to add shared components into React NX Monorepo?
I've created React NX monorepo using npx create-nx-workspace@latest, also added 2 simple projects inside.
npx nx g @nrwl/react:app todo-list
npx nx g @nrwl/react:app admin


It's generated 2 apps within the workspace.
How can I create libs that will contain shared components (Tabs, Search etc.) that can be used in both applications?
How can I add the libs app and then use components within my applications?
I've created third app and called it libs but it's not working...
Also all tutorials contains libs folder by default once generating nx monorepo
